# How to append Sku in product name in Magento.?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying this but it seems that it is not working....

```
      <div class="product-shop <?php echo $primaryColGridClass; ?>">
<?php 
$productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
$pos = stripos($productName);
$pos === false 
?>
         <div class="product-name">
             <h1><?php echo $productName; ?></h1>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Could you please try this code as this is working fine at my end.

```
</div>

      <div class="product-shop <?php echo $primaryColGridClass; ?>">


<?php 
$productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');

$sku = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('sku'));

$pos = stripos($productName, $sku);
if($pos === false )
{
    //no sku already - append now
    $productName.= ' - ' . $sku;
}
else 
{
    //sku aready present
}
?>

         <div class="product-name">
             <h1><?php echo $productName; ?></h1>

         </div>
```